# Increment Buttons with 1 when clicking wix code

Tags: velo

i am new with wix code so i need to know how can i use buttons that will increment text with 1 when the user click and then i need the number of clicks to be stored in database and then maker this number the same when the page is reloaded.
thanks in advance.

```
var num = 0;
```

$w.onReady(function () {

$w("#text2").text= num.toString();

```
$w('#button1').onClick(function (){    
$w("#button1").link = "http://wix.com";
```

num ++;
    $w("#text2").text= num.toString();

$w("#dataset1").setFieldValue("number", $w("#text2").text);
$w("#dataset1").save();

});

});

Answer (score 0):

Rajaa,

is the field $w(“#text2”) connected to your dataset using the Wix Editor connection panel?

The answer to this question depends on how your page elements are wired up. If they are then you need to be careful what you change in code and when because the javascript you write might be impacted by the Wix Dataset engine working automatically due to the element binding.